# Adding anchor points in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I love draw.io but I am annoyed by how hard it seems to be to create custom shapes or modify existing ones. This does not seem possible to do in a "WYSIWYG" manner with your mouse, but rather you need to do this in SVG/XML.

I have the following figure and I want to draw a trapezoid around A B C E F and one around D G H.

[image: diagram]

I tried the "card" shape, but there seems no way for me to change where the anchor is for where the cut off starts or ends. I've been looking through the internet and I cannot figure this out - even though this seems like such a simple problem.

Is there any simple way to draw such figures, e.g. just click the anchor points that you want like in illustrator and then connect them?

Answer (score 1):

draw.io is a diagramming app, not drawing app so some things can't be done easily. You could try and add waypoints (right mouse click > Add waypoints)and experiment with that or check if shapes from draw.io library (there are many) can suit your needs.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

As Marija said, it's not possible because Draw.io is a diagramming app and not a drawing app.

However, I see two workarounds for your diagram.

###### Workaround 1: Polygon

If you really want a trapezoid, use the polygon shape and adjust it's corners.

###### Workaround 2: Line

Use a line and put one and at the starting point (your spot A) and one end at the ending point (your spot C).
Then take the light blue dot that appears when you hover over the line and pull it to all the inbetween points (your spot E, B and F)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know this may not be the answer that you're looking for, but perhaps you could just make a custom shape using the lines, as to me it seems as though there's no way to do what you are asking.